# How can I override Spring Boot application properties for tests without using profiles?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I find extremely scarce all information about having a typical setup in Spring Boot with a main production db and a test in-mem db.

- There's no convention for test properties, application.properties in test override the ones in main obviously, and there's no fallback mechanism like application-test.properties -> application.properties. I don't want to use profiles, because I would like them to define strictly the environment, which is another dimension (local, production), and I would need the cartesian product main-local, test-local, main-production, test-production..
- So I am gonna let Spring do magic for me, therefore I set @DataJpaTest annotation on my RepositoryTest. Spring certainly creates the H2 db on-the-fly, but I don't find a way to set a custom schema or enable H2 console, as application.properties are ignored.

How it is the most standard way to deal with this?

P.S. I think the easy way to do that is overriding properties in my test by means of `@SpringBootTest(properties = { "h2.console.enabled: true", "h2.console.path: /myconsole" })` but I cant find the way for @DataJpaTest to bind them

Comment: H2 console requires a web environment which is not available in a `DataJpaTest`. Why do you want to set a custom schema in an ephemeral in-memory  database?

Comment: To easy debug all db working

Comment: The traditional way for registrring the bean in spring is by calling org.h2.server, i dont know why should we have a webenv configured, i never needed it in pre-boot spring

Comment: I really think profiles are exactly what you are looking for. I understand you may only want to use them in a certain way but this is one of the use cases many developers use them for.

Comment: Could also use your build tool, as in copy the required properties file to your run-time environment as you require, but I would rather use profiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just provide a second application.yml / application.properties used for tests at path `src/test/resources`. The one located in test context is used for tests, when you run the application the file at `src/main/resources` will be used.

E.g. the production config (using postgres and ddl-auto validate to keep your data) placed at `src/main/resources`:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
```

And the test config (using H2 and ddl-auto create-drop) placed at `src/test/resources`:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    username: sa
    password:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
```